# Select rows from mysql table on basis of time difference

Tags: mysql, datediff

I have a table `table1` where there is a column called `time`. Its of MySQL's DATETIME data type. I want to select records from `table1` where time in the `time` column is just 10 days old. How can I do that with simple SQL.

I am using PHP with mysqli OOP

Answer (score 0):

use this query.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE 
                    DATE(time) = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 10 DAY)";
```

Answer (score 0):

To get all the rows exactly 10 days old, you can use the [date](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date.asp) and [date_sub](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_sub.asp) function.

```
SELECT 
    column1
FROM 
    table1
WHERE 
    DATE(table1.time) = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 10 DAY)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query:

```
 select * from table1 where DATEDIFF(date(time),date(now()))<11;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `table1` WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 10 DAY) <= time;
```